# Replace several parts of a string with values from a lookup table

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cell with text: "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee".

I have a lookup table with values corresponding to the different strings. E.g. "aaa"=1, "bbb"=2 etc.

I need to create a single cell with text where the "aaa" etc. have been replaces with their corresponding value.

E.g. the string "aaa,bbb" should create the string "1,2".

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your lookup table is in columns A:B and the text you want to replace in cell C1 then try:

`=JOIN(",",ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(C1,","),A:B,2,0)))`

Comment: Btw. Any way to make the join() work within the arrayformula?

Comment: I don't think so unfortunately.  You could wrap an IFERROR() around it  and copy the formula down to the bottom of the column though.  You'd then get a blank result for any empty rows rather than an error message

Comment: Ok. It's at little less dynamic, but works in my case. Thanks again!